# 1 Storage with 1 "big" partition + 2 servers

Tags: storage, dell, failover, direct-attached-storage, high-availability

I need to setup an "cold fail over" to our database server.
Since we cannot run an real HA because an software issue, I'm planning to connect 2 server to a single storage. If main server fails, I just need to start database service in second, as database files are "shared" on storage.

I that possible? I think NAS isn't an option because I need maximum IO speed.

Our preferred vendor is DELL, but you can suggest me other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a Dell solution, I'd probably be looking at a MD3000 which you can then attach to both nodes.  Depending on your filesystem, you may be able to have it mounted on both servers at the same time, or maybe not (not really a huge issue if you cant).

Alternatively, if you're using Linux, you should look at DRBD which will allow you to replicate the data at a block level between the two nodes.  Combine it with OpenAIS/Pacemaker and you can have automatic failover as well.  This also has the additional benefit of not having a single point of failure (your storage server).

Comment: @rodjek I'm running Windows 2003 x64 with NTFS. With MD3000 can I do that? DELL vendor specialist sell me an MD1000, and today (when we was installing it) DELL technical support told me that isn't possible...

Comment: As far as I'm aware (and according to Dell's MD1000 page), the MD1000 can only be connected to a single host.

Comment: Now with the "white elephant" in my hands I know that. Do you really think that MD3000 do that I need it to do?

Comment: I'm a linux guy and I don't really know your use case.  You're better off talking to your Dell account manager - you may be able to trade in the MD1000 as well.

Comment: IIRC the MD3000 can be purchased with 2 host connection ports.

Comment: @phoebus Indeed it can, hence the "which you can then attach to both nodes" ;)  The question is, can his MD1000?

Comment: @rodjek You'll note that two comments above mine, the OP asked "Do you really think that *MD3000* do that I need it to do?", which I was answering.

Answer (score 0):

In split mode an MD1000 can be connected to two hosts, but not to the same storage array on the MD1000. An MD3000 can in fact do this, as phoebus has stated.

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/md1000/en/HOM/operate.htm#wp1056917